# SQL Subquery - executing a select statement for every "ID" returned in a row

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have two tables, a `person` table and an `orders` table. The `person` table includes a `personID` field and a `name` field, among others. The `orders` table contains an `orderID` field, among others. I want to return information about one or more persons, but in addition to that, I want to use the personID to query additional information, to be returned in each row. For example:

```
personID    name    +    orderID
  120       John           5000
```

My query right now is as follows:

```
SELECT p.personID, p.name
FROM person p
WHERE p.name = "John"
```

I would like to return a list of people matching that name query, but for each result, also use the personID to look up a specific order (one order) which falls between two dates, has an "active" flag checked, etc, or if that order doesn't exist, return a null for orderID.

Comment: How is Person and Order tables related. I mean what is the foreign key?

Comment: What happens if John has more than one order in the date range submitted?

Comment: The primary key in the Person table is `personID`. `personID` is also a foreign key in the orders table.

Comment: According to the rules of the database, there should only be one order within the parameters I'm going to provide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that the specified **Person** will only have 1 **Order** between the given Dates and Flag.

```
SELECT p.personID, p.name, (Select OrderId From Orders o Where o.PersonId = p.personID and o.Date Between Value1 And Value2 And o.FlagColumn = 'Active') As OrderId
FROM Person p
WHERE p.name = "John"
```

You can also you `JOIN` for this.

```
SELECT p.personID, p.name, o.OrderId
FROM Person p
JOIN Orders o On p.PersonId = o.PersonId
WHERE p.name = "John" And
      o.Date Between Value1 And Value2 And 
      o.FlagColumn = 'Active'
```

Comment: I used a variation on the first example you used (the subquery) and it worked wonderfully. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know that @BigMario. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select p.* 
From Person p
JOIN Orders o 
     ON p.PersonID = o.PersonID AND 
     (o.OrderDate BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-07-30') AND
     (o.IsActive = 1)
WHERE p.Name = 'John'
```